# Google Hangout Application does not receive start_data, I get null

Tags: javascript, xml, google-api, google-hangouts

My problem is when I call **gapi.hangout.getStartData()** function **I get null.**

This is my hangout button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<script src="//plus.google.com/hangouts/_/api/dev/hangout.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder-div">
</div>
<script>
    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', {
        'render': 'createhangout',
        'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '297670343437', 'start_data' : '123456', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
        'hangout_type': 'onair',
        'widget_size': 175
    });
</script>
```

And this is my xml file (hangout app):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Proxied Hangout" height="200" width="550">
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>
    <Require feature="rpc"/>
    <Require feature="views" />
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html"><![CDATA[
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//plus.google.com/hangouts/_/api/v1/hangout.js"></script>

  <script>
    var youtubeLiveIdReady = function (ev){
      var start_data = gapi.hangout.getStartData();
      console.log(start_data); //I get null

      var data_obj = {};
      data_obj['start_data'] = start_data;
      data_obj['youtube_id'] = gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId();

      console.log(data_obj);
    }
    gapi.hangout.onair.onYouTubeLiveIdReady.add(youtubeLiveIdReady);

    function onClientReady(){
      console.log("client ready...");
    }

  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientReady"></script>

  ]]></Content>
</Module>
```

I don't know what is wrong, this code worked weeks ago, but now actually no.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it following from this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004114/google-hangout-button/30150592#30150592