# Google + hangout button

Tags: html, google-hangouts

I am trying to add a google hangout button to my html file as shown below but when I run the html page , the button does not show.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-rr"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',     'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175
    });
     </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First please check if any errors showing up in browser console using f12 key when on browser and reload the page.
- Try adding this script as well alongwith platform.js to the page you want the hangout button.
  `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Hope this helps

Example code:-

```
<div id="hangout-button-holder"></div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

gapi.hangout.render('hangout-button-holder', { 'render': 'createhangout', 'topic': 'Its a demo app dont freak out', 'hangout_type': 'onair', 'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'LOCAL_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  For me, the kicker seemed to be adding the `client:plusone.js` script.